# ngCordova demo application build failed

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am trying to build [the demo app of ngCordova](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/tree/master/demo).

```
cordova platform add ios
cordova run ios
```

But build failed with the following error messages.

> The following build commands failed:
>   **CompileC** build/ngCordova\

Demo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ngCordova\ Demo.build/Objects-normal/i386/applicationPreferences.o ngCordova\ Demo/Plugins/com.simonmacdonald.prefs/applicationPreferences.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1 failure)

> ERROR running one or more of the platforms:  Error code 65 for

command: xcodebuild with args:
-xcconfig,/Users/westhigh/github/demo/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,ngCordova Demo.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,ngCordova Demo,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/westhigh/github/demo/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/westhigh/github/demo/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Comment: I mentioned steps in answer in below post
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523038/adding-google-plus-login-to-ionic-app/37525072#37525072][1]